# Nodemailer send email with information from MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, nodemailer

I'm trying to do password recovery with Nodemailer.  Basically, the user will input an email address to an HTML form and an email will be sent using Nodemailer.  That email will contain the password from the MySQL database.  My problem is, the password shows as "undefined".

```
app.post('/Forgot_Password_V1', function(request, response) {
    var connection = request.app.get('pool'); 
    connection.query('SELECT password FROM accounts WHERE email = ?', [request.body.email], function(error, results, fields) {  
https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?pli=1
    { account: results[0] };

        var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            service: 'Gmail',
            auth: {
                user: 'user',
                pass: 'password'
            }
        });

            //send to the email entered in the form input
            var mailOptions = {     
                from: 'email',
                to: request.body.email,
                subject: 'Password Request',
                text: 'You have requested to recover the password of your account.\n\n' +

                request.password + // I tried this
                account.password + // I also tried this
                '\n End.\n'
            };
```

The output for the password in the email shows "undefined".  I've been trying different things to no avail.  Can somebody please help what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: do a console.log for account , and see if the result is being returned

Comment: Try results[0].password,   request.password is incorrect becasue password is in db query result not in api request. Also it very bad procedure to store password in db as plain text, use hashing.

account =  JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results[0])), then account.password should work as well.